# Expanding of td tag when added a row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a sample html page as shown below
[image]

But when i add a row underneath the row which encompasses a div block and form in itself, i encounter a behaviour where the td tag of the first row increases in its width as shown in the image below

[image]

The source code for the page is below

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div style="left: 100px; position: relative; width: 400px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label style="font-size:17px;"> Select the operation:</label>
            </td>
            <td><select style="font-size:15px" property="" id="operation" name="operationSelection" onchange="categorySelector()">
                <option value="addOp"> Addition </option>
                <option value="searchOp"> Search </option>
                <option value="listOp"> List </option>
                <option value="updateOp"> Update </option>
                <option value="deleteOp"> Delete </option>      
            </select></td>                           
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="add" style="position: relative; width: 200px;">
                <form name="addForm" action="udm_2.jsp" method="POST">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label style="font-size:17px;"> Select the Gender:</label>
                    </td>       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="addCategory" value="male" checked="checked">Male<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="addCategory" value="female">Female<br>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit"/>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried changing width of the td but in vain
so can someone please explain the reason for the behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean the 200px on line 19?

Comment: Transform your table into `div` elements with `overflow: visible` property. The purpose of HTML table is to show *tabular data*.

Comment: This is the default behavior or html tables. The `Select the operation` cell is right above the form cell you create (the one with the inner table). All cells that form the same column in a html table would align their widths.

Comment: Why are you using a table if you don't want the columns to line up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have `width: 200px;` set to the div that is a child of your first `td` element inside your second `tr` element.

Table cells(td) always have the same width as the longest cell in that column.
this means that your first `td` elment(and all other elements in that column) will have a width of 200px.

To solve this either remove the 200px width from the div or move the select box to within the same td element as its label like so:

```
<td>
  <label style="font-size:17px;"> Select the operation:</label>
  <select style="font-size:15px" property="" id="operation" name="operationSelection" onchange="categorySelector()">
            <option value="addOp"> Addition </option>
            <option value="searchOp"> Search </option>
            <option value="listOp"> List </option>
            <option value="updateOp"> Update </option>
            <option value="deleteOp"> Delete </option>      
   </select></label>
</td>
```

If it's not necessary to use tables in this instance I would recommend switching to divs instead. Using tables is great if you actually need to show your content in a tabular format. If this is not the case then tables aren't the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Using HTML `table` elements for styling purposes is considered a **bad practice**. You should really think about using other elements, `div`s for example. Much better then `div`s would be elements with a semantic value. I would also recommend to place your CSS in a separate CSS file. Think also about `em` units in your CSS instead of `px`.

Here you have a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BQf99/)** with `div`s.

The HTML code with `div`s:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/css/styles.css">
</head>    

<body>    

<div class="wrapper">

  <div>
    <label class="label"> Select the operation:</label>
    <select id="operation" name="operationSelection" onchange="categorySelector()">
      <option value="addOp"> Addition</option>
      <option value="searchOp"> Search</option>
      <option value="listOp"> List</option>
      <option value="updateOp"> Update</option>
      <option value="deleteOp"> Delete</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="add" class="form-wrapper">
    <form name="addForm" action="udm_2.jsp" method="POST">
      <div class="label"> Select the Gender:</div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="addCategory" value="male" checked="checked" id="male">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="addCategory" value="female" id="female">
        <label for="female">Female</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The CSS in your styles.css:

```
.wrapper {
  left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.form-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.label {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

select {
  font-size: .9em;
}
```